# Python Tkinter issue

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime


date1 = datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 1)
now = datetime.datetime.now()

def timer_label(label):
    def time_remaining():
        daysdiff = str(date1-now)
        label.config(text=str(time_remaining))
    time_remaining()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Days to Closure')

label = tk.Label(root, fg="red")
label.pack()
timer_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='CLOSE', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

when I run it I get the following output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya3pn.png)

I would like to see this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RurBv.png)

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label you're displaying is the function (which is a printable object) and not the calculated time left.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import datetime


date1 = datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 1)
now = datetime.datetime.now()

def timer_label(label):
    def time_remaining():
        # Also here no str typecast is required
        daysdiff = date1-now
        label.config(text=daysdiff)
    time_remaining()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Days to Closure')

label = tk.Label(root, fg="red")
label.pack()
timer_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='CLOSE', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's great - thank you - makes much more sense now.